# Leads that will help me to develop Eclipse line numbering like plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to develop a little plugin for Eclipse, and I would be very grateful if someone could give me some leads. Basically all a need to know is how current line numbering panel is implemented, so I need either some source code of custom plugin with similar functionality, or where in eclipse sources to look after current line numbering functionality.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `IVerticalRulerColumn`. As per javadoc:

> A vertical ruler column is an element
>   that can be added to a composite
>   vertical ruler
>   (org.eclipse.jface.text.source.CompositeRuler).
>   A composite vertical ruler is a
>   vertical ruler with dynamically
>   changing appearance and behavior
>   depending on its actual arrangement of
>   ruler columns. A vertical ruler column
>   supports a subset of the contract of a
>   vertical ruler.

**Class to look for:** `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor` most of the editors extend this.

**Method to look for:** `createLineNumberRulerColumn()`