# Implementing horizontal line numbering in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need a horizontal line numbering in Eclipse RCP application, do you have any recommendation where to start looking?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, your question really made me think...

To be honest, I'm not sure, but I'd look at how the vertical line numbering is implemented and go from there. 
Here's the [source for the AbstractDecoratedTextEditor](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java.htm). Take a look at createLineNumberRulerColumn(), and see if this takes you anywhere.

My guess is, if it's doable, it's probably not an easy task. Good luck :)!

Comment: I think he already knows about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836743/leads-that-will-help-me-to-develop-eclipse-line-numbering-like-plugin. Though there are multiple ways of doing this. :)).

Comment: @Favonius: Ah, I didn't see that question. Yes, he obviously knows about it, then. Well, I'm sorry I can't provide him with a better answer than the one I gave. Maybe somebody else in the SO community will be able to do that.